# How can one see the Moderator Scores outside an election?

Tags: support, election

During a Site's Moderator Election i remember that the nominee posts has this score next to their profile image which was made up by a number of factors such as meta participation and flagging.

I am wondering if there is a way to view these outside an election so one can try and work on it before the next one comes up?